Current leakage in the earth for MV motor
After we check the IR for rotor and stator  for our MV motor this motor for FAN ,  as a result the value acceptable and IR good value,  After that we found some current leakage flow in the earth cable its from 2 to 9 A as attched in the photo.
After I checking this cable I found connect in 1 node ( 1 cable for motor & 1for fan shield)
I need to know from where this current coming in the earth cable ?
It's capacitive coupling ?
The earth cable polling together with MV cable high voltage.

I would not expect any current on the ground wire under normal operation.  Is this single phase?  Is there a voltage from Neutral to Ground while running?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
